# Disable CCMenuItem until animation finished

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an `CCMenuItem` and I want to disable it until an animation is finished, but I **don't** want to disable all touches with:

```
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher.dispatchEvents = NO;
```

Any easy solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CCSequence` to first use the animation action and when that is done you create an action that calls a function with the `CCMenuItem` as parameter and in that function make it enabled.

Code example: (PS: It was a long time since I used cocos2d.)

```
{
...
CCMenuItem *menuItem = [CCMenuItem itemWith...];
menuItem.isEnable = NO;
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem, nil];
[self addChild:menu];

[menuItem runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCAction actionWith...], [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(enable:)], nil]];
...
}

-(void)enable:(CCMenuItem *)item {
    item.isEnable = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me! The cool thing is, it even works with blocks as actions: CCCallBlock *activateTouch = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
            menuItem.isEnable = YES;
        }];

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the CCMenuItem with

```
CCMenuItem *item = [[CCMenuItem alloc] initWith...];
item.isEnabled = YES;
```

and enable it afterwards.